# How do I create a non-stacked barplot with data labels using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am processing [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE156388) dataset (bottom of the page) in R for a project.
First I load in the data:

```r
count_data <- read.table(file = "../data/GSE156388_read_counts.tsv", header = T, sep = "",
                         row.names = 1)
```

I then melt the data using reshape2:

```r
melted_count_data <- melt(count_data)
```

Then I create a factor for colouring graphs by group:

```r
color_groups <- factor(melted_count_data$variable, labels = rep(c("siTFIP11", "siGl3"), each = 3))
```

Now we get to the barplot I'm trying to make:

```r
ggplot(melted_count_data, aes(x = variable, y = value / 1e6, fill = color_groups)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + labs(title = "Read counts", y = "Sequencing depth (millions of reads)")
```

The problem is that this creates a [barplot](https://cln.sh/sH8wX0) with a bunch of stripes, leading me to believe it is trying to stack a ton of bars on top of each other instead of just creating one solid block.

I also wanted to add data labels to the plot:

```r
+ geom_text(label = value / 1e6)
```

but this seemed to just put a bunch of values on top of each other.

For the stacked bars problem I tried to use `y = sum(values)` but this just made all the bars the same height. I also tried using `y = colSums(values)` but this obviously didn't work because it needs "an array of at least two dimensions".
I tried figuring it out using the unmelted data but to no avail.

I just kind of gave up on the labels since I wasn't even able to fix the bars problem.

EDIT:
I found a thread suggesting this:

```r
ggplot(melted_count_data, aes(x = variable, y = value / 1e6, color = color_groups)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + labs(title = "Read counts", y = "Sequencing depth (millions of reads)")
```

Changing `fill` to `color`. This fixes the white lines but results in some (fewer) black lines. Looking at [this new chart](https://cln.sh/SBgZJy) leads me to believe it might actually be pasting a bunch of charts on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

url <- paste0( "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/", 
               "?acc=GSE156388&format=file&file=GSE156388%5", 
               "Fread%5Fcounts%2Etsv%2Egz")

tmpfile <- tempfile()
download.file(url, tmpfile)

count_data <- readr::read_tsv(gzfile(tmpfile),
                              show_col_types = FALSE)

count_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  mutate(color_groups = factor(name, 
                          labels = rep(c("siTFIP11", "siGl3"), each = 3))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)/1e6, color_groups = first(color_groups)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = color_groups)) +
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2)), nudge_y = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Read counts", x = "", fill = "Type",
       y = "Sequencing depth (millions of reads)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold", "deepskyblue3")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried this but I got this error `invalid 'labels'; length 6 should be 1 or 5` for this line `factor(name, labels = rep(c("siTFIP11", "siGl3"), each = 3)))`. I guess it's because the name variable doesn't include "siTFIP11_1" anymore?

Comment: I have updated the code so that it is fully reproducible. Assuming you have the tidyverse  and readr installed, then copying and pasting the code above in a fresh R session will download the file, save it to a temporary file, read it in the correct format, reshape it and plot it exactly as above.

Comment: I see what caused the issue now. When I initially load the data into a table I used `row.names = 1` which screwed it all up. After having removed that bit your first answer works fine too now. Thanks for all the help!